# A question about groups, sets and subsets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

There is a very well known property:

> If $G$ is a group and $H$ a subgroup and we have $x \in H$ and $y \in
>  G - H$ then $xy \in G - H$. $\,(1)$

The problem if there are much examples when you don't have only $G,H$ and $G - H$, you can have for example:

$x \in G - P$, $y \in H - P$ then how is $xy$ ?

$x \in G - P$, $y \in P - H$ then how is $xy$ ?

$x \in G - P$, $y \in P - \{ e \}$ then how is $xy$ ? 
 (and examples can be more)

($P$ is a subgroup, the same logic like principal theorem $(1)$)

I don't understand the logic here and where $xy$ is in.. so how can i know where the product $xy$ is ?

Comment: Cross-posted on [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1978834_a_question_about_groups_sets_and_subsets).

Comment: yes, i know, i posted here too because no one is answering.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Usually $G/H$ denotes the set of left cosets of $H$ in $G$.  Is that what you intend here?  If not...what did you intend?

Comment: \ means exclude.

Comment: What is the nature of $P$?  Is it a subset of $G$? a subgroup of $G$? a normal subgroup of $G$?

Comment: P is a subgroup.

Comment: Please edit your post to clarify your terms.  $G/H$ is standard notation for left cosets.  If you meant to use that notation in a different way, please write out what you intended.

Comment: I used $\backslash$, not "/" , please read careful.

Comment: @lulu i edited now, i hope is better.

Comment: But why would one expect any sort of general answer here?  For the first case, say $y=x^{-1}$.  Then $xy=e$ which is in all three of $G,P,H$.  Or say $P=e$, $H=G$ and $y\neq x^{-1}$.  Then $xy\in G$ and $H$ but not in $P$. Is there any reason you think that there should be some universal answer?

Comment: Maybe is not an universal answer, but i thinked it can be. For example if $x \in H - \{e\}$ and $y \in G-H$ then why $xy \in G-H$ ?

Comment: Because if $xy$ were in $H$ then, since $x^{-1}\in H$, we'd have $x^{-1}xy=y\in H$ counter to assumptions.

Comment: And, of course, you might be able to find other  specific situations in which one can prove something.  But, in other situations more complicated things can happen, as my examples illustrate.

Comment: So $x \in H-P$ and $y \in G-H$ then $xy \in G-H$ is true only $P = \{ e \} $? The problem is you can find a lot of problems with that property and don't say to you why is that exactly, just throw directly and you are supposed to think others thing are true and they are not.

Comment: I didn't say anything like the claim you describe.  I just gave an example, I made no general claim about it.  You can try to generate your own examples!

Comment: Ok, so what do you suggest in cases like that, how to think about the results?

Comment: Try examples!  Group theory is complicated.  Just because there aren't simple, one line rules that govern a situation doesn't mean you can't analyze it.

Comment: Okey, thank you for your answers! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there's no general answer. You can understand the result you quoted as the converse statement of the closure of $H$: in particular, since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, for any $x,y\in H$ we have $xy\in H$. What the result states is that if $x\in H$ and $xy\in H$, then we must have $y\in H$ too (for if $y\not\in H$, then $xy\not\in H$). This is something that's intuitively clear and which you should expect to be true.

But now if $P$ is a subgroup of $H$, a statement like $x\in G-P,y\in H-P$ is hard to make use of. What the conditions say is just that $x,y\not\in P$ but $y\in H$ while $x$ is any element in $G$. There's no reason to think that there would be an analogous result here.

Comment: What about $x \in G-H$ and $y \in H-P$?

Comment: @sticknycu Well, then now that's the same as saying $x\not\in H$ and $y\not\in P$ but $y\in H$. But notice the second condition is barely saying anything here, since $P$ hasn't been specified. So by the result you quoted we have $xy\in G-H$, but I doubt there's much more to be said.

Comment: Hmm, what about $P$ is subgroup of $G$, what about subgroup of $H$ ? I'm asking because i think if $P$ is subgroup of $G$ you can't say anything, but if $P$ is subgroup of $H$ then $xy \in G-H$

Comment: @sticknycu Again, the condition that $y\not\in P$ is really weak, so I doubt it is a useful one. You should probably try out some examples yourself, make some conjectures and see if it's true for some test groups: maybe start with the easiest $\mathbb Z_n$ or $S_3$ or something along those lines.

Comment: @sticknycu It doesn't really matter, if $P$ is a subgroup of $G$ then $y$ is still in $H$, so your quoted result still applies regardless (well, unless $H\subseteq P$). We can always conclude $xy\in G-H$ but not much more.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your time.

Comment: Glad to help, cheers!